# How to get the description text from metatag field

Tags: 9, meta-tags

A content type in my Drupal 9 instance uses the Metatag module. I want to extract the 'description' metatag value and include it in a twig template (for the node).

But when I look at the variables available, it looks like `field_metatag` contains PHP `serialize()`-ed code.

I want to do something like

```
<div class="the-description">
  {{ node.field_metatag.description|e('html') }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the serialized data via `node.field_metatag.value`.

But seems there's no ready-made unserialize Filter for Twig. And the tags are hidden from the node because they are supposed to be used on page-level instead. So you either write an unserialize filter yourself or preprocess the description into the template.

I found the following preprocess to be working.

```php
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_node().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];

  $tags = \Drupal::service('metatag.manager')
    ->tagsFromEntityWithDefaults($node);

  if (!empty($tags['description'])) {

    $description = \Drupal::service('metatag.token')
      ->replace($tags['description'], ['node' => $node]);

    $variables['my_description'] = strip_tags($description);
  }
}
```

```
{% if my_description %}
  {{ my_description }}
{% endif %}
```